# AlarmManager fires at different times

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've created and deployed to the Google Play an alarm app. As always do, I performed plenty of tests in 8 different real devices (I don't work with the emulator) running different api levels, rooted/ non-rooted, different timezones, among other features.

The problem is that after hitting over 10'000 downloads, a few users are complaining about the alarm firing 1 hour before the specified time, and some others (4x the amount) complain that the alarm fires 1 hour later. I'm getting this from different places in the world, and I get 5 stars also from the same places.
Instantly I thought I was using timezones by mistake in some places of my code, but the truth is I'm only using

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
```

that kind of instantiation is the one I used through all my code. I set the alarm using the system AlarmManager like:

```
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    long triggerAtMillis = 0;
    if(nextAlarm != null){
        triggerAtMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() 
                + 60*1000*alarmDifference(nextAlarm, gc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), gc.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true)
                - 1000*gc.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    }else{
//          Log.d("", "nextAlarm: NULL");
    return;
    }

    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE_ALARM_BROADCAST, intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, operation);
```

The alarmDifference method is quite simple:

```
public static int alarmDifference(Alarm alarm, int hour, int minute, boolean inverse) {
    int hours = hour - alarm.getHour();
    if(inverse){
        hours *= -1;
    }
    if(hours < 0)
        hours += 24;

    int minutes = minute - alarm.getMinute();
    if(inverse){
        minutes *= -1;
    }

    if(hours==0 && minutes<0){
        hours = 23; //this happens if we set the time to the current hour
    }

    if(minutes < 0)
        minutes += 60;

//  Log.d("", "Time left: "+ hours+" hours, " + minutes+" minutes");
    return hours*60 + minutes;

}
```

I'm targeting api level 17, so I don't run into the problem of the system not honoring delivery times and have to work with *AlarmManager.setExact(...)*.

To wake up my service I'm using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver so I don't have to handle the WakeLock on my own.

I've done plenty of research in the site and have tried different approaches without any luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you checking AM and PM?

Comment: Notice in the code that I'm working with Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY; that's 24 hour format, so I don't need to check for am/pm.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use next for find troubles:

in your app load world time from internet services (for example, http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=YahooDemo) and compare with time with timezones on device. You can determine what is trouble: in device globally or in your app.

Comment: The app should work offline, so that is not valid. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Also you can try use for compare time from GPS (NMEA) data (this time is not allways correct). This is not need internet permission, but need location permission.

Comment: That way has more drawbacks 'cause the user may have location disabled, or not get location updates in a while. Won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is in this line:

```
triggerAtMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() 
                + 60*1000*alarmDifference(nextAlarm, gc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), gc.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true)
                - 1000*gc.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

This operation is **not** guaranteed to happen atomically. In other words,

- gc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
- gc.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

Can happen at different times, e.g. while the clock is changing over from 14:59:99 to 15:00:00, so you might get hours 14 and minutes 00, or hours 15 and minutes 59

Instead I would extract the hours/minutes/seconds from an immutable timestamp value.

Comment: I'll try this one, but according to Google analytics the users are not setting the time at XX:59, nor XX:00. I'll let you know.

Comment: The GregorianCalendar object **gc** is not changed after instantiation, therefore its immutable. The alarm diference is calculated with a custom Alarm object that is a POJO, so the **triggerAtMillis** value doesn't changes if the system time changes.